# Behat3 SensioLabs Page Object Extension

Tags: php, symfony, bdd, behat

I am trying to configure Behat3 to use SensionLabs PageObject Extension, but looks like it won't find it. I have the extension added to composer.json file and installed in vendor folder when I look into it.

Here is my behat.yml file

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      path:
        features: features/site
        contexts:
          - SiteContext

    system:
      path:
        features: features/system
        contexts:
         - SystemContext

  extensions:
    SensioLabs\Behat\PageOBjectExtension:
      namespaces:
        page: [Page]
    MageTest\MagentoExtension\Extensions: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: "http://somewebsite.local/"
      selenium2:
        wd_host: http://127.0.0.1:4444
        browser: firefox
```

Comment: You've got a typo in the class name. "B" should be a "b" in "PageObjectExtension".

Comment: Thanks for that, but class namespace also changed.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a full namespace. SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to have to have figured it out myself, I was using incorrect extension path it should have been

```
SensioLabs\Behat\PageObjectExtension\ServiceContainer\PageObjectExtension
```